# OneDrive SDK SSL Error

Tags: php, onedrive

I am having an issue sending requests from our PHP application to the OneDrive SDK.

I am using the following package to integrate our application with OneDrive:

https://github.com/krizalys/onedrive-php-sdk

It has been working perfectly fine for months then all of a sudden this morning it started responding with an SSL error:

SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104

I have tried to fix it all sorts of ways:

- Updating all the dependencies within composer
- Updating curl, openssl and php7.0-curl on the server (was already latest versions)
- Creating a new OneDrive account to test to see if the problem persists (which is does)

When I created a new OneDrive account, the demo that is available through the GitHub package I linked earlier worked, but as soon as I started sending requests from our application it is now returning the same error as above.

I have been checking the status of OneDrive through various websites and social media but nothing has caught my attention with relation to the problem I am having.

We are using a basic Microsoft account, not a business one, I am not sure if maybe Microsoft has cottoned on to us using their SDK for business purposes and maybe blocked our application from sending requests, but I am unable to find any documentation online that relates to business vs non business SDK usage.

I have also been trying to find a support/contact page so I could contact Microsoft to confirm my theory above but I was unable to, so I am here hoping that my question could be answered.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check in your php.ini if you openssl extension is active: http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php

Comment: I can confirm the openssl extension is enabled, also why would it randomly disable after months of working? :(